# How to build the MVVMToolkit from source code?

Tags: mvvm-light

I'd like to understand the proper way to build the MVVM toolkit from the source files on codeplex for a WP7 sample app.  I've got the source associated with codeplex changset 47157 by lbugnion  Apr 18 at 10:42 AM  1300 associated with Release: MVVM Light Toolkit V3 SP1 (2).

I've got VS2010 and Windows Phone Developer tools installed.  I see the VS10 dir that presumably contains the VS2010 solution files.  Do I just open that .sln file in VS2010 and build all?  The distributed binaries contain versions of the dlls suffixed with WP7.  I don't see those version of the dlls generated when I build the VS10 solution file.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the WP7 bits. Unfortunately they are missing from the VS10 folder and are instead in the old GalaSoft.MvvmLight folder. Plain and short, I messed up. The "old" folder was historically the root. When I added projects for SL4 and WPF4, I did so in the VS10 subfolder (not my brightest idea). And when I added WP7, I apparently did so in the wrong folder. This is really weird.

I have a flaky internet connection in the moment (I am on the road) so I won't be able to fix the issue before a couple of days. I made a note and will fix the CodePlex code base ASAP. More info will be given on my blog http://blog.galasoft.ch.

Cheers,
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 the solution you should open is source\VS10\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.sln. The Silverlight projects may not open if you don't have the Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio installed. Don't worry about this if you're only building the WP7 version of the toolkit assemblies. The solution structure is confusing at first because it uses linked file references.

Actually, now that I look at the VS10 solution, it doesn't look like there are any WP7 files under the structure. I think you're correct, and the Visual Studio 2010 solution doesn't build the Windows Phone 7 assemblies.